# Why Typescript Mapped tuple types shows all options in AutoCompletion/Intellisense?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I am very new in Typescript and I have an issue which I don't know how to resolve it :(.

Basically I want to create a list of tuple from a list of components. The first element of the tuple is the element's name (keyof MyComponents) and the second elements is its attributes.

(See code below)

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQSwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZWAWQJ4GED2BbABxzCkgGdhgBvAKEst0gXFgC5q77K4AbAVxAATAPzsARjhw8oCMJy5IeCMmQByCPFFHAyEGOADm84AF8ANMYAqCA%201pdK0AB4Rtu-WCMPgi5Wo1a7O6GxpQAFkKCpOKS0rLGJjSJNAD0KQDiUBDAEGGoANZQGBQ4cDl5wDwgusClwHgYPvhEJOQ0EBgEqACi0pqQwAC8wIUYdZi4hMSkEGR0qRlZ5agIEHogYnzQFFFdYIKGtWDLwFB9M8BgAe2dqAAKIEj5AIJr%20pvbADyWpy6kghRelB%20hAAHxDYAPJ6fCbNabkADalgAumYRkVxtg4a1ZkjkaCaAssDAZNBgAgcnwCNIcrdgAigSC0a91h8oGRkQtyfsTqtWVt2cBdv8jiczsCZjQoE4iDBsh0usBLFSacMqMBCZQGecBuB0WMyrCpjiOcB2NqJZA0VCXm8NgKyJ9GTNQZykgjRpjJi0ZhzNQtLBEKAB3HAwfIUWSCXlbHBNQjSCAgYjAUPhihdeBQJAQHgYGhIYg1bbZdg2lnvB2fADk1gM1fBaoigiix3YiB4ZCgyQDQfJnbjaYjBaL8vZEAAjGalSrUMMEQAiOsLtHq5ut9sITvdzlpbowGBh4AfUAQasUMBhvBb8kUXKocUg4DVxirFgwatCnDssDV7JhBAADdUHvYACEPTMOmAddogkKQZDkQswGLccACZp2Vak53pBdGAgZgSBgFdqGgyJomADsuxMN1CSAA)

```
 interface MyComponents  {
    Container: {
      fluid?: boolean
      className?: string
    },
    Tag: {
      text?: string
      className?: string
      hidden: boolean
    }
}

//Get the keys of the list of my components
type Element = keyof MyComponents
 
//Get the attributes depending on the element name
type PickAttributes<T extends Element> = Pick<MyComponents[T], keyof MyComponents[T]>

//Create a mapped tuple type [Element, Attributes]
// and the attributes depend on the element
export type Tuple = { 

  [Element in keyof MyComponents] : [Element, PickAttributes<Element>]

}[keyof MyComponents]

 

const attr : PickAttributes<'Tag'> = {hidden : false} //This works and the auto completion works perfectly

const tuple1 : Tuple = ["Tag", { hidden: false}] //This also works

const tuple2 : Tuple = ["Container", { hidden: false}] //Error but it's normal as the element 'Container' doesn't have the property hidden:boolean
```

Everything works perfectly but there is a small problem for autocompletion.
When I type the first element (Container, Tag, ...), the auto completion of the second element (its attributes) shows all the possible attributes even the wrong ones.

**As an example if I type 'Tag' for the first element it suggets me 'fluid' but 'fluid' is only available in 'Container' !**
[Intellisense shows all options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3zZz.png)

**And when I choose fluid, it also knows it's incompatible...**

[Typescript knows it's incompatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klHsy.png)

So my question is:
**How can I restrict the autocomplete to only shows valid attributes depending on the element's name ?**

Any help will be appreciated ! Thanks !**

Comment: I don't have an answer, but autocomplete has to work when your code isn't even completely syntacticly valid. So I imagine that its safety is highly reduced compared to the full type checker.

Comment: Your code is correct.  You can write the tuple as `[Element, MyComponents[Element]]` instead of `[Element, PickAttributes<Element>]` but that doesn't change anything.  The autocomplete I think is just something that you have to live with.

Comment: Thanks @AlexWayne for you response. Yes it seems it's the case here :(

Comment: Thank you @LindaPaiste for your response appreciate it :) I'll try if I can come up with an another solution with this specific case.

Comment: I would guess it's related to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729) specifically -- TypeScript is simplifying/flattening the type for performance reasons in the autocomplete. Forcing a generic appears to work ie `export type Tuple<T extends keyof MyComponents> = [T, MyComponents[T]]; const test3: Tuple<"Tag"> = ["Tag", {}]`

Comment: @Zweihänder Thanks for your response. But then how can I define an array of Tuple<> ?  I think I can't do something like that :  const test4 : Tuple<keyof MyComponents> [] = ...

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to your title question as to **why** intellisense does that, but I can give you two options to answer the question "*How can I restrict the autocomplete to only shows valid attributes depending on the element's name?*":

Option 1, Use objects instead of arrays to model the tuple:

```
export type TupleAsObject = {
                               // If desired, the keys can now be more descriptive
  [Element in keyof MyComponents] : { 0: Element, 1: PickAttributes<Element> }
}[keyof MyComponents]
const test3 : TupleAsObject = {0: "Tag", 1: { /* type will be narrowed correctly */ }}
```

- Pros: It does what you want, and allows you to be more descriptive with property keys.
- Cons: It's no longer an array, so if you are using array methods on the tuple anywhere, you'll lose that functionality.

Option 2, use a tuple constructor function:

```
function buildTuple<E extends Element>(el: E, attrs: PickAttributes<E>): [E,PickAttributes<E>] {
  return [el, attrs];
}
const test4: Tuple = buildTuple("Tag", { /* types will be narrowed correctly */});

// works with arrays of Tuples
const tuples: Tuple[] = [
  buildTuple("Tag", {hidden: false}),
  buildTuple("Container", {})
]
```

- Pros: Does what you want and keeps the value as an array-tuple.
- Cons: Adds a function call.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=1#code/AQSwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZWAWQJ4GED2BbABxzCkgGdhgBvAKEst0gXFgC5q77K4AbAVxAATAPzsARjhw8oCMJy5IeCMmQByCPFFHAyEGOADm84AF8ANMYAqCA+1pdK0AB4Rtu-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-aoFcMAwL2UCCE0aGFhAPCNAGKSmMkgbBsAoYRlGMYAEwJjQcB8GARbRscmwIYIn5QE6vzQPsgLnqCAAUZy7mifIwGQh6PLa-JfN0oIAJTmt0ZhHnabKOvJ672MAJIQHwMDHAiZxiW8fqJI+YDPuyEAACzsJxEJsTwHEqlAgkgTY4GbjBCqCvBiHIZcCBoRhWGPjhRb4eRKQmApADchI0JZz5uZJSpuQi67DAinDOa5mYeaB3lUBEghRGA7CIDwZBQHFFiUPlnEeYwEDMCQMAlXFNDIkAA)